# How to exchange one-time authorization code for access token with flask_oauthlib?

Tags: python, oauth, flask, google-oauth, flask-oauthlib

I'm building an API with the [Python Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in which I now receive a "one-time authorization code" from an app which I supposedly can exchange for an access and refresh token with the Gmail API ([described here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)).

I've been using [Oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for regular authorizations in the browser, which works perfectly fine. So I found [this page](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/authcode.html) with some example code of how to implement this. The code in the example starts off with `from your_validator import your_validator` and I'm immediately stuck. I found something [here](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/server.html#implement-a-validator) about implementing a custom validator, but at the top of that page it says that [flask_oauthlib](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib) already implemented this.

Does anybody have an example how to exchange a one-time authorization code for an access and a refresh token with flask_oauthlib? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an example using Oauthlib but here's one using oauth2client library.
https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-python

Looking at flask_oauthlib, [`handle_oauth2_response`](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/flask_oauthlib/client.py#L619) seems to be the method you'll need to use to exchange `code` with `access_token`.

Comment: It took me some time, but in the end I solved it with  handle_oauth2_response. I had to manually overwrite flasks request.args unmutual dict (which is a bit ugly), but it works. Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction!